# Some user profile pics aren't appearing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-profile

During the past couple of days, some **[users' profile pictures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users)** have stopped appearing. It happens to most but not all profile pics, and doesn't seem to stay with any type of user (moderator, new, etc.).

The usercard on the users missing pics also does not load, or appear to try when hovered over. On the Election page, some users are missing their pics by the descriptions, but they work fine in the Choices area. The page is fully loaded while this is happening.

[image]

**Does anyone know what's going on here?**

I am running Windows 10 and using Google Chrome v.50.0.2661.102 m. I just updated to the latest version of Chrome and it still is happening. This is also happening on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: May have something to do with your internet connection. Also have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Just tried in Firefox; same result. @Dragonrage my internet should be just fine (although TWC sucks).

Comment: Are you using a tracker-blocking browser extension? Some tracker-blocking extensions block Gravatar by default (as it's a tracker).

Comment: Do you mean the completely white with no shadow, white with a shadow, and/or white with the image icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gonna guess those are Gravatar images? Sounds like something's down somewhere between you and Gravatar. We've had a couple reports to that effect earlier this week, but unfortunately there's not much we can do.

Comment: By "Gravatar images", are you referring to the default designs as opposed to uploaded pictures?  If so, most of the pictures missing in that screenshot are not those.

Comment: @JohntheGreen Default identicon designs or avatars deliberately uploaded to gravatar (for example, that's where Raven Dreamer's avatar comes from).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yep; this is it. I checked a bunch of users' avatar source links, and all of the missing ones are hosted by Gravatar. The Gravatar site is also down for me.